# How to get coin address balance from bitcoind server?

Tags: php, bitcoin, json-rpc, bitcoind

Im running bitcoind on my local ubuntu box.

I see that "bitcoind getbalance [account]" will get me the total balance of a user account. And thats good and that works fine.

How do I get the balance of a individual users wallet (assuming they have more than 1 wallet associated with their account). For example, I have Wallet 1 with 10 coins and Wallet 2 with 20 coins for a total balance of 30 coins. How do I check the balance of the individual wallet (wallet 1 or wallet 2)?

I dont see any commands to view an individual addresses balance.

Answer (score -1):

You may also take a look at those:

- getreceivedbyaddress <*coinaddress> - it does display you how many *coins have been moved to this particular address. It doesn't subtract payouts, which should be handled internally.
- getreceivedbyaccount - use this instead of above if you use accounts.
  Additionally, you can provide a second parameter to those being a minimal number of confirmations.